# Error: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, function, methods, dictionary, error-handling

I wrote the following code to count the node of an XML file:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> ExtractNodeInfo(string fileContent)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument;
        xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(fileContent);
        var ediNodes = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/EDI");
        Dictionary<string, int> nodeCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (XmlNode nodes in ediNodes)
        {
            FileManager.nodeRecurse(nodes, nodeCount);
        }

        foreach (var entry in nodeCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But it gives me the following error: 'XmlFileManager.FileManager.ExtractNodeInfo(string)': not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Read the error again `not all code paths return a value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't returning a value.

You need a return statement at the end of your method, in this case:

```
return nodeCount;
```

Comment: @user1255009 click the checkbox next to the number of this answer to mark it as 'the answer'.

Answer (score 2):

Your method's signature tells that it has a return type of `Dictionary<string, int>`.

In your method `ExtractNodeInfo`, you do not have a `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a return type, but you're not returning anything anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What everybody else has said.

I see two other problems:

First, `XmlDocument.Load( string )` takes a *filename* not XML data. To do that, you need to use the `LoadXml()` method.

Second, it looks like you're trying to count nodes by name. Why are you writing code to walk the XML tree? Let the framework work for you. Code you don't write it code you don't have to test or debug.

The method `SelectNodes( string xpathExpression )` hands you a flat list of all nodes in the document matching the specified XPath expression. For instance:

- `//*`
  every node in the document, including the document root, regardles of its depth within the document.
- `//foo/bar[@type='data']`
  every `bar` element with a `type` attribute whose value is `data` and whose immediate ancestor is a `foo` element at any depth in the document.
- `/EDI` (your XPath expression)
  the root node of the document so long as it is named 'EDI'.
- `/EDI/*/foo`
  all `foo` elements that are 2nd level children of the document's root element, `EDI`.
- `/*`
  a list of one element, the root element of the document, regardless of its name. You might want to use the `SelectSingleNode()` method here, since you know you won't get more than one element back.

Write an XPath expression that gives you the specific set of nodes you want and use Linq for objects to build the dictionary, thus:

```
private static Dictionary<string,int> CountNodesByName( TextReader reader , string xpathExpression )
{
  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument() ;
  xml.Load( reader );

  Dictionary<string,int> instance = xml.DocumentElement
                                    .SelectNodes( xpathExpression )
                                    .Cast<XmlNode>()
                                    .GroupBy(
                                      x            => x.Name ,
                                      (name,nodes) => Tuple.Create( name , nodes.Count() )
                                      )
                                    .ToDictionary( x => x.Item1 , x => x.Item2 )
                                    ;

  return instance ;
}
```

Given the above,

```
TextReader             reader          = OpenSomeXmlDataSourceForReading() ;
Dictionary<string,int> nodeFrequencies = CountNodesByName( reader , "/EDI//*" ) ;
```

will produce a dictionary with frequency counts by name for every child node at any depth so long as the root node is named `EDI`.